# Save Plot and Print Statement in same file

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, save

I've spent the last few days writing a program that makes several different plots and writes a print statement for each describing certain conditions. The loop saves each plot before moving onto the next iteration. The plots all save successfully, but not with their associated print statements.

My code:

```
if a < b:
  print('A is less than B')
if a > b:
  print('A is greater than B')

ax.set_title('Event Number {}, Event Type: {}, Event Outcome: {}'.format(current_event_number, current_event_type, current_event_outcome))
sns.scatterplot(x, y, hue = color, legend= False)
label_point(x, y, start_loc.Name, ax) #Function to label scatterplot
sns.lineplot(x1,y1, color2, legend=False, ci = None)
plt.plot(x2, y2, color='red', marker='o') 
plt.savefig('Event{}.png'.format(i), format='png')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

This code is all part of the same loop, and when it's running, the conditional print statements show, they just don't save with the figures. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The print is to the output and the plots are to the PNG. If you want the print to the PNG you may put in the title or like that because you cannot output text in a PNG, it is only for graphic. Instead you can make a log file. In the log file you do all the print and you also write the file name of the PNG. Then everything is recorded in the log and you can connect later the files when you require it. To print in the log you use write.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and post your answer

Comment: You answer better? You may answer also.